# How to change Laravel format date for timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel, laravel-4

Example code:

```
$user= user::orderBy('id')->first();
echo $user->created_at;
```

The above code will return something like `2014-07-25 22:41:19`. How can I only get only year, month or day from it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use PHP `DateTime` object:

```
$dt = new DateTime($user->created_at);
echo $dt->format('Y').' - ' . $dt->format('m').' - '.$dt->format('d');
```

All format modifiers are the same as for `date()` function ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)) so you can also merge them:

```
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do it like (if it's already a Carbon object):

```
echo $user->created_at->year;
```

If it's not a `Carbon` object then you may do it like:

```
echo Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->year;
```

You may use `month`, `day` and more, check the [manual](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon).